# How to capture a bake program running without rendering window using NSight

Tags: directx, raytracing, nsight

I'm writing a DXR baker program, since it's just a baker generating ray traced results to a buffer, I didn't write any rendering window for this baker. It just keep calling DXR's dispatchRay API in a loop, and read back results to a buffer.

So I'm wondering if there's any way to use NSight to capture the DXR API calls to see the TLAS and BLAS structure. NSight keeps saying "Searching for attachable application" after launching my program using NSight frame debugger.

Do I have to write a rendering window for the NSight to capture frame?

Comment: Have you tried PIX?

Comment: @MaicoDeBlasio No, I guess this may be the same result, because all capture frame program need to capture "Present()" to isolate different frames. So I ended up writing a rendering window with empty swapchain to solve this problem.